# remove n columns from CSV file

Tags: linux, shell-script, csv

I have a csv file with data as below :

```
12,1234,28-07-2018 05:28:12.21,ABC60,3456,28-07-2018 05:28:12.21,AB60,7580,28-07-2018 06:28:12.21,PQ
```

I need to remove all date columns from the file through Unix.

Comment: Are the positions of the date columns always the same?

Comment: Yes position is always same for date column

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no embedded commas inside a comma-delimited field, and that you want to remove columns 3, 6 and 9.

```
$ cut -d, -f1,2,4,5,7,8,10 <file
12,1234,ABC60,3456,AB60,7580,PQ
```

The `cut` command extracts the given columns out of a file. By default, tabs are used as column delimiters, but with `-d,` we set the delimiter to a comma. The `-f` option takes the column numbers (or ranges of column numbers) that are to be extracted.

Using `csvcut` from [CSVkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/), which is a real CSV parser, we can also handle fields which contains embedded commas:

```
$ csvcut -c 1,2,4,5,7,8,10 file
12,1234,ABC60,3456,AB60,7580,PQ
```

This tool also handles cutting on column *names* if the file has headers for each column.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
echo "12,1234,28-07-2018 05:28:12.21,ABC60,3456,28-07-2018 05:28:12.21,AB60,7580,28-07-2018 06:28:12.21,PQ" | awk -F ','  '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i !~ "-") printf "%s,",$i}' 

12,1234,ABC60,3456,AB60,7580,PQ,
```

- prints the columns which are not having `-`

Answer (score 0):

Albeit not `awk`, but...

```
tr ',' '\n' < csv | grep -E -v '^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}' | tr '\n' ','
12,1234,ABC60,3456,AB60,7580,PQ,
```